# How to create text border in React Native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

In React-Native, how do I add font borders to Text-components?

I've tried using `border` and `shadow{Color, Radius, Opacity, Offset}`, but haven't gotten that to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view-style-props

Answer (score 34):

The official docs have this information for you. You can find it on this site: [Text Component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html). There it shows which props you can use to change the behaviour and style of the component. As you can see there are some specific Text styles but also the styles you can apply on a [View Component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#style). And if you follow that link it shows you the border styles. So, what you're looking for is maybe:

```
borderColor string
borderTopColor string
borderRightColor string
borderBottomColor string
borderLeftColor string
borderRadius number
borderTopLeftRadius number
borderTopRightRadius number
borderBottomLeftRadius number
borderBottomRightRadius number
borderStyle enum('solid', 'dotted', 'dashed')
borderWidth number
borderTopWidth number
borderRightWidth number
borderBottomWidth number
borderLeftWidth number
```

Comment: Nor does it work for TextInput, despite what the documentation says.

Comment: I put a view outside the Text and add the style to the view, it works perfectly.

Comment: None of these things create a text border

Comment: If you are trying to add a border to a <Box>, using ```borderWidth``` worked for me

Answer (score 32):

you can emulator border as two attributes :

```
textShadowColor color
textShadowOffset {width: number, height: number}
```

Ex:

```css
textshadow:{
    fontSize:100,
    color:'#FFFFFF',
    fontFamily:'Times New Roman',
    paddingLeft:30,
    paddingRight:30,
    textShadowColor:'#585858',
    textShadowOffset:{width: 5, height: 5},
    textShadowRadius:10,
  },
```

Comment: Why is this answer so bad rated here?
Thats the exact answer for the given Question! I think the question was a border to the Text... means the font... every single character.
And the above  textShadow... Stylesheets work very well for this.

Comment: One must reduce the offset width and height values to 1 and maybe the radius too to really emulate text borders

Comment: This doesn't allow you to create text borders (unless you want an extremely thin border)

Comment: Because 'textShadowRadius' creates a blur.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 26):

Is currently not working for android. Try wrapping it within a view like this one:

```
<View
  style={{
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "thistle",
    borderRadius: 50,
  }}>
</View>
```

Comment: Didn't work in Android for me!. Ref: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29

Answer (score 19):

You need to set `borderColor` and `borderWidth`.

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking for something similar to how CSS [-webkit-text-stroke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke)
 works, why not try [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg#text)?

```
import Svg, { Text } from "react-native-svg";

<Svg height="50%" width="50%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <Text
    stroke="black"
    strokeWidth="1"
    fill="white"
    color="#ffffff"
    fontSize="45"
  >
    Yay!
  </Text>
</Svg>
```

Comment: It boggles my mind that the first answer that actually provides a solution that does what the OP is asking for is so far down with only 4 upvotes

Comment: Very smart solution, can recommend this one. You can easily turn this example into an `OutlinedText` reusable component too!

Answer (score 2):

As noted by KChen, you need to add both borderColor and borderWidth. Just updating this answer for later versions of ReactNative (note the usage of '**styles.bigblue**').

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Image, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class HelloWorldWithBorder extends Component {
        render() {
                return (
                                <ScrollView>
                                <Text style={styles.bigblue}>HelloWorld WithBorder</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.bigblue}>HelloWorld WithBorder</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.bigblue}>HelloWorld WithBorder</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.bigblue}>HelloWorld WithBorder</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.bigblue}>HelloWorld WithBorder</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.bigblue}>HelloWorld WithBorder</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.bigblue}>HelloWorld WithBorder</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.bigblue}>HelloWorld WithBorder</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.bigblue}>HelloWorld WithBorder</Text>
                                </ScrollView>
                       );
        }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        bigblue: {
                color: 'blue',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: 20,
                borderColor: 'black',
                borderWidth: 1
        }
});
```

[image]

This was using a combination of the tutorial from [Styles](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html) and [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-a-scrollview.html)

Comment: A breaking change from ReactNative? Shocking! No, I'm kidding. But seriously I wrote this a while ago so I am not surprised if something changed in RN 0.59. Unfortunately I'm not too active with RN any longer.

Comment: LMK if you can fix this in 0.59 and feel free to edit, or let me know how I can edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
 paddingTop: 10,
 borderWidth: 1,
 borderColor: 'red'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to at least set the borderWidth, it must be set to an integer. The default border color is black, you can change the color with borderColor

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a bottom border to `Text` component like this:

[image]

I did the following:

the border is a `<View/>` inside another one with `flexDirection : 'row'`

here is my code:

```
<View style={styles.titleContainer}>
   <Text style={styles.title}>Horaire de prière</Text>
   <View style={styles.borderContainer}>
     <View style={styles.border} />
   </View>
</View>
```

and the style:

```
titleContainer: {
    flex: 0.2,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center'

  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 18,
    marginBottom:2,  
  },
  borderContainer:{
    flexDirection:'row',
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',

  },
  border:{
    flex:0.28,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#428947',

  },
```

you can modify border size with flex.