# React Native font outline / textShadow

Tags: css, react-native

Is it possible to add an outline or textShadow to a font in react native to achieve something like this (white font with a black outline):

[image]

In CSS on the web its possible to add a text shadow or an outline to a font, to give the text a border that follows the font, something like this:

```css
h1 {
    color: yellow;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

Is it possible to do something similar in react native?

I took the CCS snippet example from this stack overflow post on how to do it with CSS: [CSS Font Border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570972/css-font-border)

Comment: I found this post very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924616/how-to-create-text-border-in-react-native/44454883
There is refer to https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg#text

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is possible through the following properties:

```
textShadowColor color
textShadowOffset ReactPropTypes.shape( {width: ReactPropTypes.number, height: ReactPropTypes.number} )
textShadowRadius ReactPropTypes.number
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html

Actual completed pull request:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/4975

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure if my question was clear, but I am not looking to put a square/rectangular border around the text. Rather I am trying to create a shadow effect that follows the contours of the font itself so I can have for example a white coloured font with a black outline

Comment: React Native's textShadow* styles halfway achieve what you want.  The problem is that the border only renders in one direction, not all around the text.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this?  I'm doing to make my text look just like the picture in the question and am running into the same problem at the shadow only works on direction and its also rendered behind the text and we are trying to outline the text

Comment: @bzlight check the answer from me if it is still something you're looking for

Answer (score 18):

There is at least one way to make it look like this on both ios and android:

[image: iPhone simulator screenshot with outlined text]

**Idea:**

The idea is to use multiple shadows on the Text object. We can do it by wrapping Text component with View and clone the same Text object multiple times with different shadows to make them using different directions.

**Implementation:**

Here is the code for the wrapper component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { Children, cloneElement, isValidElement } from "react";

type Props = {
  children: any,
  color: string,
  stroke: number
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  outline: {
    position: 'absolute'
  },
});

export class TextStroke extends React.Component<Props> {
  createClones = (w: number, h: number, color?: string) => {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return Children.map(children, child => {
      if (isValidElement(child)) {
        const currentProps = child.props as any;
        const currentStyle = currentProps ? (currentProps.style || {}) : {};

        const newProps = {
          ...currentProps,
          style: {
            ...currentStyle,
            textShadowOffset: {
              width: w,
              height: h
            },
            textShadowColor: color,
            textShadowRadius: 1
          }
        }
        return cloneElement(child, newProps)
      }
      return child;
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {color, stroke, children} = this.props;
    const strokeW = stroke;
    const top = this.createClones(0, -strokeW * 1.2, color);
    const topLeft = this.createClones(-strokeW, -strokeW, color);
    const topRight = this.createClones(strokeW, -strokeW, color);
    const right = this.createClones(strokeW, 0, color);
    const bottom = this.createClones(0, strokeW, color);
    const bottomLeft = this.createClones(-strokeW, strokeW, color);
    const bottomRight = this.createClones(strokeW, strokeW, color);
    const left = this.createClones(-strokeW * 1.2, 0, color);

    return (
      <View>
        <View style={ styles.outline }>{ left }</View>
        <View style={ styles.outline }>{ right }</View>
        <View style={ styles.outline }>{ bottom }</View>
        <View style={ styles.outline }>{ top }</View>
        <View style={ styles.outline }>{ topLeft }</View>
        <View style={ styles.outline }>{ topRight }</View>
        <View style={ styles.outline }>{ bottomLeft }</View>
        { bottomRight }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

If the text is not big, you can also use only 4 directions instead of 8 to improve performance:

```
<View>
    <View style={ styles.outline }>{ topLeft }</View>
    <View style={ styles.outline }>{ topRight }</View>
    <View style={ styles.outline }>{ bottomLeft }</View>
    { bottomRight }
</View>
```

**The usage:**

```
<TextStroke stroke={ 2 } color={ '#000000' }>
  <Text style={ {
    fontSize: 100,
    color: '#FFFFFF'
  } }> Sample </Text>
</TextStroke>
```

You can also use multiple Text objects inside since the wrapper copies all of them.

**Performance:**

I haven't checked the performance for this solution yet. Since we're copying text so many times it maybe not great.

**Issues:**

Need to be careful with the `stroke` value. With higher values, the edges of the shadows will be visible. If you really need a wider stroke, you can fix this by adding more layers to cover different shadow directions.

[image: sample with wide stroke]

Comment: Thanks!!! This is the only way I found to do this! It's not perfect at 100%, but is the best solution EVER till now! You made my day  @lub0v !

Comment: When you use `text-align: center`, the stroke doesn't match up. Do you know how you would do that?

Comment: It works even with icons ! Well done

Comment: This works well. I am looking to have transparency in between instead of fixed white with black borders. Anyway i can achieve that?

Comment: Thanks man, this shuld be implemented as a default feature!

Answer (score 0):

I installed [expo-font](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/font/) and imported a ['hollow' Arial font](https://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/Arialic_Hollow.font).

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, fontError] = useFonts({
    'Inter-Black': require('../../../public/ArialHollow.ttf'),
  });

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded || fontError) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded, fontError]);

  if (!fontsLoaded && !fontError) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
      <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter-Black', fontSize: 30 }}>Inter Black</Text>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>Platform Default</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

App.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-font",
        {
          "fonts": ['./public/ArialHollow.ttf']
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Consider other outline fonts such as [Carbono](https://www.1001freefonts.com/carbono-pw.font).