# Is there outline property in react-native?

Tags: css, react-native

Outline property is in CSS, but I tried to use outline property in react-native.

I encountered the following message while using outline property with react-native.

`error:outline property is not a valid style property`

Anyone know the property instead of outline property of css in react-native without install another package.

Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Did you mean borders: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view-style-props ??

Comment: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/48

Comment: No I means outline. In css,there are properties such as padding,border,margin,outline.but in react-native,outline is not a valid property.

Comment: possible reply <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38755258/react-native-font-outline-textshadow>

Comment: The difference between outline and border is that outline overlays on top of the element, while border adds extra thickness (depending on the border width) and therefore will alter the height/width of the element you apply it to. Outline is perfect for debugging purposes, quickly identifying and color coding elements based on their component type for example.

Answer (score 4):

In React Native we cannot give it by using `outline: "red 2px solid"` instead we need to break it into individual styles. Think of it as we are styling it through a javascript object.

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#e7622e",
    borderColor: "#fcfdfb",
    borderWidth: 2,
    outlineColor: "#523009",
    outlineStyle: "solid",
    outlineWidth: 4,
  },
  title: {
    color: "white",
  },
});
```

`outlineColor: "#523009", outlineStyle: "solid", outlineWidth: 4` are the property name that it understands.

Comment: Using `outlineColor`, `outlineStyle`, and `outlineWidth` all at once worked, thank you! Thank god. I was beginning to be afraid that `outline` simply didn't exist in React Native, but it does!

Comment: How to do that with css modules?

Comment: Those who want to use it, note it is available only for web

Answer (score 1):

can do something like below

```
 if (Platform.OS === 'web') (inputStyle as any).outline = "none"
```

Comment: `as any` is never safe

Answer (score 0):

```js
 
     searchInput: {
                width: "25rem",
                padding: 6,
                outlineColor: "green",
                outlineStyle: "solid",
                outlineWidth: 4,
                borderRadius:10,
                color:"#fff",
              }
```

we are dividing outline property into color, style  & width

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -2):

```
style={{
        height: 40,
        width: "95%",
        borderRadius: 20,
        backgroundColor: this.state.boxColor,
        marginHorizontal: 10,
        fontFamily: ConstantFontFamily.defaultFont,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        paddingLeft: 35,
        minWidth:
            Dimensions.get("window").width >= 1100 ? 630 : 393,
        outline: "none"
    }}
```

Comment: Could you, please, explain your answer?